# Need to display friends list from facebook on to my app ? Need help in FBML

Tags: facebook, fbml

After authenticating the user, I need to get the users friends list.
I got the user name and photo by below code-

```
<'fb:profile-pic uid='loggedinuser' facebook-logo='true'><'fb:profile-pic> <br/>
"Welcome, <'fb:name uid='loggedinuser'  useyou='false'><'/fb:name>.<br/><br/>
```

I need to display friends list here, please suggests how to do this with uid attribute in hand.

Answer (score 1):

it's impossible doing this using only [x]fbml due there is no such feature
so you have to use JS [FB.ApiClient.friends_get](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.ApiClient.friends_get) and then display the retrieved friends

ps: why this topic was at main page???? didn't even look at post date :-S